# JPA - Hibernate - Oracle SQL - query by checking hours

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, timestamp, hour

I'm using JPA - Hibernate - Oracle SQL. I have an object that has a date variable "startDate" of type Date in java, Timestamp in Oracle.

What I want is a JPA Query that returns all those objects with start HOUR of ANY day before "09:00"  ( HH:MM )

For example in this week I have 2-3 objects each day starting at "08:00". I want to find those that start before "09:00"

Any suggestions?

Comment: The question is very vague. You need to specify your table that is mapped to the object (entity), the columns.
Also if you are using JPA 2.0 or 1.0?

Comment: The question is not vague. I gave all the needed info minus that JPA is JPA 1.0.  

Imagine an Object with String name;  and Date startDate;
Imagine a TABLE  with column NAME ( VARCHAR ), START_DATE ( TIMESTAMP ). It's enough

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Event where hour(startDate) < 9").list();
```